# Pertaining to origination of IP address

Tags: email, ip-address

If an email sent from either France and Canada and yet, the IP shows Washington State & California.  Using email addresses from @live.com and @yahoo.com.  Does this mean that they originated from WA & CA and NOT France & Canada?

Comment: where are you checking the IP?

Comment: emails don't have the original senders IP. Only the servers that it went through.

Answer (score 2):

Those Washington State and California IP addresses are the address of Yahoo's and Live's mail servers. The sender's IP is not included in the email for privacy and security reasons.

Why are you trying to find the IP? Is there another way to achieve your goal beside with the IP?